# 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression when using async/await inside nested functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Basically Visual Studio Code gives me the note `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.` but I am note able to track the actual problem down. Of course my example here is a bit nested and therefor a bit more complex than it maybe has to be. It all starts with an array where I want to check it a value is valid. If on value fails the test, the *.every* function should end.

```
myList.every(function (value) {
  if(value == null) return false;  
  //other stuff for preparation
  return _handleValue(value);
});
```

value is a complex datatype so the *_handleValue* function is splitted into different subfunctions. Some of the function are using promises some (atm) don't. Please ignore the functions in the if block because the code is simplified and this is not causing the problem.

```
async function _handleValue(value) {
    if (somePreChecks(value)) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (valueIsType(value)) {
      return await _someHandlerwithPromise(value); //<-- Using await here. 
    } else if (valueIsOtherType(value)) {
      return _someOtherHandlerWithoutPromise(value);
    } 
  }
```

The function `_someHandlerWithPromise` has some call which are using callback. Anyway this should not be a problem as long as I call `reject()`.

```
  function _someHandlerWithPromise(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       foo.acceptValue(value, function (data) {
        _updateSystem(data, function (err, data) {
          if(err){
            //Do something
          }
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Actually this worked pretty well elsewhere where I do not use the await function. But because the *.every* is not able to handle asynchronous methods, I am forced to use await.

Comment: "*But because the `.every` is not able to handle asynchronous methods, I am forced to use await.*"  - uh, `every` can not handle `await` either. The promise returned by `_handleValue(value)` is always truthy.

Comment: @Bergi Do you have another solution how to solve this problem?